# Spring LDAP ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context) User Group update Issue

Tags: spring-ldap

We are trying to update user group for a newly created user. Updating users in User Group works fine, but when we try to update the User group information for a user (memberOf) doesn't work as expected.

Issues:

1. `ldapTemplate.modifyAttirbutes` for user group update removed user group association for existing users in LDAP which has become very critical issue for us.
2. `ldapTemplate.modifyAttirbutes` didn't update the user group information for the user which we are trying to update user group (memberOf) attribute.

Another mischievous behaviour is, same code works fine in Development environment as expected but it didn't work in our next level (UAT) environment.

Copied the below code snippet:

```java
Name dn = EnterpriseDirectoryServiceHelper.buildDn(uid, getDirectory(directory));
DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
String[] memberOfArr = context.getStringAttributes("memberOf");
List<String> memberOfList = new ArrayList<String>();
if (memberOfArr != null)
    memberOfList = Arrays.asList(memberOfArr);

List<String> fullyQualifiedUserGrps = 
        EnterpriseDirectoryServiceHelper.buildMemberUserGroups(
                userGroupNames, userGroupsBaseDirectory, baseDirectory);
for (String group : fullyQualifiedUserGrps) {
    if (!memberOfList.contains(group))
        context.addAttributeValue("memberOf", group);
    System.out.println("group inside context addition" +group);
}

ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
```

Looking for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

The problem when working with attributes that contain distinguished names is that semantic equality for distinguished names differs from string equality. For instance the DN `cn=John Doe,ou=Accounting,dc=example,dc=com` is semantically equal to the DN `CN=John Doe, OU=Accounting, DC=example, DC=com`. Luckily, `DirContextAdapter` has support for this out of the box.

When adding and removing values to an attribute using `DirContextAdapter` it attempts to figure out which values are added and removed in order to make the actual update as efficient as possible. This does not work as desired if you handle the distinguished names as strings, but if you explicitly tell `DirContextAdapter` to treat the values in an Attribute as distinguished names it will work just fine. The way to tell `DirContextAdapter` to treat an attribute with distinguished name equality is to supply `javax.naming.Name` instances to `addAttributeValue`/`removeAttributeValue`, e.g.:

```
public void addUserToGroup(String uid, String groupName) {
  DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(buildUserDn(uid));
  ctx.addAttributeValue("memberOf", buildGroupDn(groupName));

  ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
}
```

Removing a user from a group would work similarly, only use `removeAttributeValue` instead. Now, if `buildGroupDn` returns a `javax.naming.Name` instance, `DirContextAdapter` will automatically make sure to add/remove the appropriate attribute values.